# flask and sqlalchemy db upgrade creates mysql database tables on local host but creates mysql error 1146 on linux vps

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am at my wits end and realise the problem I have is not very defined. I am happy to provide anything else necessary for trouble shooting.

I am trying to deploy a web app that I have build. It is running fine on my local computer running a python 3.10 venv on pycharm and a local mysql database. I have cloned the git repository on the Linux VPS running ubuntu 22.04. I have installed all requirements and a mysql server with a user 'gnome' and a database 'gnome_hat'.

on sudo mysql -u root I can use gnome_hat, but SHOW TABLES; indicates it is empty
(this is expected since I want them to be created when I first initialise my db.models through flask

my .env is set to DATABASE_URL=mysql+pymysql://gnome:@localhost:3306/gnome_hat
I know this is working because I used mysql root on the local machine and that (obviously) didn't work and I was told I couldnt use that user, changing the .env worked.

However when I use `flask db upgrade` in the venv I am given a number of problems in the code described as `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'gnome_hat.stakeholder' doesn't exist")` and `(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)`. However, I expect the database to be empty and the table stakeholders to not exist yet, since this initial flask db upgrade is supposed to create the tables.

```
(venv) root@ubuntu:~/gnome_hat# flask db upgrade
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1965, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 921, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 153, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 558, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 822, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1200, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 772, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'gnome_hat.stakeholder' doesn't exist")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 1063, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1682, in invoke
    cmd_name, cmd, args = self.resolve_command(ctx, args)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1729, in resolve_command
    cmd = self.get_command(ctx, cmd_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 578, in get_command
    app = info.load_app()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 312, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, None, raise_if_not_found=False)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 218, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/root/gnome_hat/app/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from app import routes, models, errors
  File "/root/gnome_hat/app/routes.py", line 4, in <module>
    import main
  File "/root/gnome_hat/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    for x in names:
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2832, in __iter__
    result = self._iter()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2846, in _iter
    result: Union[ScalarResult[_T], Result[_T]] = self.session.execute(
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2246, in execute
    return self._execute_internal(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2141, in _execute_internal
    result: Result[Any] = compile_state_cls.orm_execute_statement(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py", line 293, in orm_execute_statement
    result = conn.execute(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1412, in execute
    return meth(
           ^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 483, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1635, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1844, in _execute_context
    return self._exec_single_context(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1984, in _exec_single_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2339, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1965, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 921, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 153, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 558, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 822, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1200, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 772, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/root/gnome_hat/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'gnome_hat.stakeholder' doesn't exist")
[SQL: SELECT stakeholder.id AS stakeholder_id, stakeholder.first_name AS stakeholder_first_name, stakeholder.last_name AS stakeholder_last_name, stakeholder.`function` AS stakeholder_function, stakeholder.organisation_id AS stakeholder_organisation_id, stakeholder.national_party_id AS stakeholder_national_party_id, stakeholder.eu_party_id AS stakeholder_eu_party_id, stakeholder.email AS stakeholder_email, stakeholder.website AS stakeholder_website, stakeholder.facebook AS stakeholder_facebook, stakeholder.twitter AS stakeholder_twitter
FROM stakeholder]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)
```

I have made sure the MySQL server has the relevant database and the user+password are correct

Comment: Did you ever delete a migration file?

Comment: I think I did at some point when the migration and updates were all tangled up

Comment: That's almost certainly what's borked it. How important is it for you to keep the history of how you got to this point? Could you have one giant migration  script?

Comment: The problem being that your local development only goes _forwards_ so it can afford to "forget" interim migrations... it never checks those. But when you go to a new system, you're now missing a link in the chain because it has to start from the very beginning and go through all of them in order

Comment: Not important at all, should I delete the migration folder completely or is it not that simple? Thank you for your responses!

Comment: I'm not sure what recommended best practice is here, but that's what I would do and have done in the past

Comment: I've tried 'rm -r ./migrations/versions/*' and 'ls ./migrations/versions' says the directory is empty, yet the problem persists. Do I have to delete something else?

Comment: It's not just deleting the folder. You need to start from scratch. `flask db init` etc. from [the docs](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Actually, with `flask-migrate` you might need to go back further. Something like [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-add-flask-migrate-to-an-existing-project)

Comment: I went to my project in PyCharm, deleted the migrations folder, deleted the alembic table in mysql and restarted flask db init creating a new migrations folder with a new first version number of the project. I committed and pushed everything to github, pulled it on the server and still get the same error =/

Comment: In your migration script, can you move the table definition of `stakeholder` up before `gnome_hat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you have is that you deleted/renamed a migration script somewhere along the way. When you're working in a local environment, this can fly under the radar - the database keeps track of the UUID of the *last* upgrade, and checks for changes from that point forward.

It's totally different when you move to a different system; each of the modifications will be made in order. It's a chain of events that will happen, in order from the very first, and you removed a link from that chain.

*Before reading further, if you suspect that this might be the case, it's worth going back through git and trying to find where this happened to restore the file(s).*

There is a **nuclear option** to fix this (and I would welcome any other answers for a less drastic solution). You basically delete all of the existing migrations and start from scratch; this is the same as [adding migrations to an existing database](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-add-flask-migrate-to-an-existing-project). The trick suggested there is to briefly swap to an in-memory SQLite3 database to generate the new migrations:

```
$ DATABASE_URL=sqlite:/// flask db migrate
```

**You will also need to delete the `alembic_version` table from your actual database**

This should be cheap and easy to do. However, there are some differences with SQLite3 and most other RDBMS and so I think it would be better if you also included naming conventions:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

meta = MetaData(naming_convention={
        "ix": "ix_%(column_0_label)s",
        "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
        "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
        "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
        "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s"
      })

db = SQLAlchemy(metadata=meta)

def create_app():
    ...
    db.init_app(app)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much @roganjosh! In the end your answer was part of the problem, another part which was uncovered by following your advice is that my main app was referring to database models before the db would be initiated. I did not see that because my local database already existed, without these tables my app wouldn't start to be initiated

Comment: I ran into another (similar) problem later on, my '@def make_shell_context()' didn't return some of my newer models (I failed to properly update this). I don't know why it worked on my local machine without, but implementing @roganjosh's answer together with fixing some bad code worked

Comment: Note that if the theory about a renamed / missing migration is correct, and your source code is version-controlled, you may be able to recover the missing migration from your version control system's history (assuming the missing script was added to version control in the first place).

Comment: @snakecharmerb indeed, I'll try edit it in somewhere. I'm a bit torn about how likely it is that such a thing could be recovered when someone has effectively deleted the version-control of their database, knowingly

Comment: The comment was more for the benefit of the OP, but thanks for taking it into account :)

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'm too trigger-happy on some things. "Blow it out of orbit, NOW" :P Thank you for the suggestion, it's important here

Comment: Well, as least you start from a known-good state ;-)